# How to inject (source) 3 different types of agents into model based on probability in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I currently have 3 agent types that extend agent `Patient`. How can I inject these types into the model based on a probability i.e. type1: 60% type2: 30% type3: 10% OR perhaps use the split block (which I have explored but haven't been able to fit it to my problem) to split `Patient` into my different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source properties, in the ***Agent*** field, write the following:

```
randomTrue(0.6) ? new Type1() : randomTrue(0.75) ? new Type2() : new Type3()
```

[image]

Replace `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` with the agent type names you have.

Also, make sure under advanced, you have Agent as the agent type otherwise you would get errors.
[image]

And in case you're confused why I have 0.75 as the probability for the second condition, it's because 30% represents 75% of the remaining 40% if the first condition is false.

Comment: Makes complete sense and works! If I used this solution mixed with an interarrival time using uniform_discr(3,5) as my Agents per arrival, essentially the probabilities should still hold true right?

Comment: Yes, it should work all the same.